# Javascript: How to append the prototype of a function to another one?

Tags: javascript, merge, append, prototype

How to append the prototype of a function to another one? Something like:

```
// Foo
function foo(){};
foo.prototype.a = 'hello';

// Bar
function bar(){}
bar.prototype.b = 'world';

// Append Foo's prototype to Bar
bar.appendPrototype(foo);

// Print
console.log(bar.prototype) // -> { a: 'hello', b: 'world' }
```

Comment: I think you mean `bar.appendPrototype(foo)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate the props of the source prototype and add each one to the destination's prototype.  This assumes that the properties of the src prototype are simple properties that can be copied (like functions or simple values, not objects themselves) which is usually the case.  If you want to allow prototype properties that are nested objects themselves, then you need to clone each property.  Usually that isn't required so here's the simpler version:

```
bar.appendPrototype = function(src) {
    for (var prop in src.prototype) {
        this.prototype[prop] = src.prototype[prop];
    }
}

bar.appendPrototype(foo);
```

Prototypes are just objects so you can just copy the properties of one prototype to another.

---

**Update several years later.**  This general concept of copying methods from one prototype to another creates what is generally termed a "mixin" where you mix in the methods of one class into another so that you create a new object that has the capabilities of both objects.  Here's an [interesting article](https://javascript.info/mixins) on the topic that helps explain.

In implementing mixins, one can now use `Object.assign()` to copy properties from one object to another in one function call rather than writing your own loop.

You can even do a mixin on classes previously declared with the ES6 `class` syntax.

A fairly common example of a mixin is where you already have a class hierarchy (so you can't just inherit) and now you want a leaf class to also be an `eventEmitter` and have all the capabilities of that emitter.  You can "mixin" the EventEmitter object and now your previously declared class also has the capabilities of an `EventEmitter`. One precaution you need to take (same as when subclassing) is that you need to make sure none of the instance property names conflict between the two object implementations because both the mixin code and your code will be accessing the same core instance object.

The alternative to a mixin in the above example is to just add a separate EventEmitter object to your leaf class instance data.  As in `this.emitter = new`EventEmitter()`.  Then, to access the emitter, rather than`this.emit(...)`, you would do`this.emitter.emit(...)`.  That works too, but is often not as convenient or concise.

Comment: A few things... first, `bar.appendPrototype` will be undefined, since your function is `bar.prototype.appendPrototype` instead. Second, this approach is potentially dangerous if you have objects as properties of a prototype, since modifying them on the destination object (`bar.prototype`) will also modify them on the source object (`foo.prototype`). So for example, suppose you had `foo.prototype.a = [1, 2, 3]` and then you did `bar.appendPrototype(foo)`, followed by `bar.prototype.a.push(4)`. Then `foo.prototype.a` is now `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Using the latest version of Chrome, I had to use `src.__proto__[prop]` and `this.__proto__[prop]` for everything otherwise an error would appear that .prototype isn't a property.

Comment: @DevinCarpenter - `.prototype` is a property of the constructor or class, not an instance.  If you want the prototype for an instance, you can use [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).  FYI, `__proto__` is deprecated.

Comment: @jfriend Gotcha so the only point when `.prototype` is used is when you're defining a constructor/class, and `__proto__` is used when changing prototype properties on an instance of one of those...did I read that right?

Comment: @DevinCarpenter - Well, there's lots of things it could be used for.  A useful reason is when you are defining a class and you want to "borrow" some or all methods from another object (but probably you already inherit from some other object so you can't easily use inheritance) as in the concept of a "mixin".  If the concept of a mixin is new to you, there are lots of references on the topic.  Here's [one](https://javascript.info/mixins).  FYI, this answer is really old, so one would probably use `Object.assign()` now to copy the properties.

Comment: @DevinCarpenter - FYI, just to be clear, `.__proto__` is a property of an instance.  It accesses the prototype object which is shared by all instances.  If you want to change or add a method on an existing object without affecting other instances, you just assign a property to that instance as in `obj.method = function() {...}`.  You mess with the prototype only when you want to affect all instances which is usually at the time you define the class.

Comment: The mixin is what I am looking for really in this scenario which is why I needed to append to the prototype, but in my case I was doing that on the class instance whereas I should be combining the classes beforehand. I understand the approaches a lot better now, so thank you for the info. Also I had no idea `__proto__` was deprecated, so doubly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do.

```
function foo(){};
foo.prototype.a =2;

function bar(){
    foo.call(this,null);
}
bar.prototype.b=4;
console.log(bar.prototype); //{a:2,b:4}
```